# User JsonWebToken in Angular -> Method Post

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angular, axios

I built an website in **node js** on the web side I manage to log in to the website using **axios**.

```
export const logInFnc = async (email,password)=>{
try{
    const login = await axios({
        method:"POST",
        url:"/api/v1/user/login",
        data:{
             email:email,
             password:password
        }
    });
    if(login.data.status = "success"){
        showAlert('success','You have successfully logged in!!!');
        window.setTimeout(()=>{
            location.assign('/global-post')
        },1500)
    }
}catch(err){
    showAlert('error',`There was a problem,you probably forgot your password or your email address is no longer valid.=>${err}`);
}

}
```

In the **browser** it works without problems as well as in the **postman**,
but in the **angular** it gives me an error of 400 and does not recognize anything

Comment: But Angular runs in a browser. How can it work "in the browser" and not in Angular?

Comment: Also, in Angular, you make HTTP requests with the [built-in HTTP client](https://angular.io/guide/http), not with a third-party library like Axios.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a problem with the URL, probably you are running a development server for angular in a port like 3000 and you have the API running in another port. Ensure this.

If the API is running in another port, you should change your URL param to add hostname + port, something like `http://localhost:{API_PORT}/api/v1/user/login`

Answer (score 0):

I actually think that you are missing some words in the URL. Just copy the URL of the request (that you are using in postman) and use it in your angular project. Or create an enviroment file to save it there, and just grab it whenever you want.